# why does it echo one thing multiple times?

Tags: php, xml

I have some problems with this code and I can't seem to figure out why. It posts both the else echo and the span echo twice. Don't I need the `}else echo{`? I basically get OPENOPENOPENOPEN (x4) when I would want it to say OPEN once.

I am quite inexperienced (as you might see), every help is greatly appreciated!

```
require_once 'feed.php';

$title = 'something';

foreach(Feed('url') as $f ) {
    if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false)
        $green_color    = 'green';

    $orange_color   = 'orange';
    $red_color      = 'red';
    $closed_text    = 'closed';
    $Maintenance_text   = 'Maintenance';
    $exception_text = 'maybe';

    if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false){

        if(strpos($f->description, $closed_text) !== false){
            echo (strpos($f->description, $exception_text) === false) ?
                 '<span style="color:'.$red_color.'">CLOSED</span>' :
                '<span style="color:'.$green_color.'">OPEN</span>' ;
        }else{
            echo '<span>OPEN</span>';
        }

        if(strpos($f->description, $Maintenance_text) !== false){
            echo (strpos($f->description, $exception_text) === false) ?
                 '<span style="color:'.$orange_color.'">MAINTENANCE</span>' :
                 '<span style="color:'.$green_color.'">OPEN</span>' ;

        }else{
            echo '<span>OPEN</span>';
        }
    }
}
```

Feed.php

```
<?php
$url = ('url');

function Feed($url) {
    $feed = simplexml_load_file($url) or die('cant connect');
    $result = array();
    foreach ($feed->channel->item as $content) {
        array_push($result, $content);
    } 
    return $result;
}
?>
```

Comment: Please start with a proper explanation of what this code is _supposed_ to do in the first place.

Comment: because *stengt* text locating multiple time in your feed, and you are executing this in loop.

Comment: Your first `if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false)` doesn't have `{}` to wrap the content, so it will only take the next line. You also use it twice, which doesn't make much sense. And all those variable declarations are fixed strings, so they can be moved outside of your loop.

Comment: **Just oes to show** Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: I see I obviously have done a lot wrong here. I tried to search for `$closed_text`, if it was true then search for `$exeption_text` if it found `$closed_text` and not `$exeption_text` then echo closed. If fount both echo open. The same for the `$kolonne_text`. See I should use `else if` instead of two IF. My first php project, just trying to learn. Thanks to everyone who tried to help :)

Answer (score 0):

First fix the first IF that does not have a `{` when I really think it should

Then you have 2 IF's where each can output a message and of course most times at least one of them will because they are both testing `$f->description` for different things, so at least one MUST FAIL and go to the ELSE part of the IF

So use a `if elseif else` contruct here to only give the `OPEN` once per loop.

```
require_once 'feed.php';

$title = 'Ev 134';

foreach(Feed('https://www.vegvesen.no/trafikk/xml/savedsearch.rss?id=604') as $f ) {
    if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false) {
//    added --------------                   ^
        $green_color    = 'green';

        $orange_color   = 'orange';
        $red_color      = 'red';
        $closed_text    = 'stengt';
        $kolonne_text   = 'Kolonnekjøring';
        $exception_text = 'kan bli';

        if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false){

            if(strpos($f->description, $closed_text) !== false){
                echo (strpos($f->description, $exception_text) === false) ?
                     '<span style="color:'.$red_color.'">CLOSED</span>' :
                    '<span style="color:'.$green_color.'">OPEN</span>' ;

            } else if(strpos($f->description, $kolonne_text) !== false){
                echo (strpos($f->description, $exception_text) === false) ?
                     '<span style="color:'.$orange_color.'">MAINTENANCE</span>' :
                     '<span style="color:'.$green_color.'">OPEN</span>' ;

            } else {
                echo '<span>OPEN</span>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: don't you need an `}` in front of else if?

Comment: You do, sorry, accidental typo

Comment: That might be so, you are in a loop, so how many time do you go round the loop where you dont find either of the things you are looking for in `$f->description`.

Comment: Any way to get around this? maybe something like if `else = OPENOPEN echo OPEN`?

Comment: If you give me a reasonable example of the data yo are processing I may be able to spot the issue

Comment: The code gathers data from a website/XML that gives reports regarding a road. In the report, it is some weather and road condition information. I want to output `open` if it isn't mentioned anything about `closed` in the text, and `closed` if it is. The same with maintenance. but if it say `could be closed` ($exeption_text) still output `open`. Hope you understand. Example output (through translate): `Snow cover. At 05:30 it was -8 degrees, light breeze and cloudy.`

Comment: So if 2 consecutive areas are NOT CLOSED, with this code you will get `OPENOPEN` and if 3 consecutive areas are open you will get `OPENOPENOPEN` so you need to be more specific about WHAT is open and it wont loook so odd, like add some other description of WHAT is OPEN

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 satisfied records from below mentioned if condition.

```
if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false){
```

Inside this if condition Both **$closed_text** & **$kolonne_text** if conditions comes into else part. So 2 times looping 2 time else part. So that's why you got 4 times SPAN. Try below one and give an UPVOTE if it solves your problem.

```
require_once 'feed.php';

$title = 'Ev 134';

foreach(Feed('https://www.vegvesen.no/trafikk/xml/savedsearch.rss?id=604') as $f ) {
    $green_color    = 'green';
    $orange_color   = 'orange';
    $red_color      = 'red';
    $closed_text    = 'stengt';
    $kolonne_text   = 'Kolonnekjøring';
    $exception_text = 'kan bli';
    $open = true;
    if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false){


        if(strpos($f->description, $closed_text) !== false){
            echo (strpos($f->description, $exception_text) === false) ?
                 '<span style="color:'.$red_color.'">CLOSED</span>' :
                '<span style="color:'.$green_color.'">OPEN</span>' ;
            $open = false;
        }

        if(strpos($f->description, $kolonne_text) !== false){
            echo (strpos($f->description, $exception_text) === false) ?
                 '<span style="color:'.$orange_color.'">MAINTENANCE</span>' :
                 '<span style="color:'.$green_color.'">OPEN</span>' ;
            $open = false;

        }
        if($open) {
            echo '<span>OPEN</span>';
        }
    }
}
```

> Note: If Both **$closed_text** & **$kolonne_text** if conditions satisfied you will face the same issue again so adjust the code according to your business needs.